# Fetch multiple data on database on Form load

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to fetch multiple data on my database in form load. But I found the code long and repeating. Can someone make this code a little bit shorter?

This is my code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = label1.Text;
        string connString = "Server=Localhost;Database=this;Uid=root;password=root";
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = ("Select Room_name from firstfloor where Room_no=(?room)");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?room", a);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    button1.Text = reader["Room_name"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        string b = label2.Text;
        string connString2 = "Server=Localhost;Database=this;Uid=root;password=root";
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connString2))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = ("Select Room_name from firstfloor where Room_no=(?room)");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?room", b);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    button2.Text = reader["Room_name"].ToString();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This may be more suited to CodeReview... codereview.stackexchange.com but yes it could be made a little more cleaner. For instance...do you really need to have two fields for the same connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you're connecting to the same database twice.
And you're doing it in the same method (it's obvious you have complete power over the decision whether to connect only once or not).

Secondly you could wrap the actual select execution in a separate method.
That separate method should receive it's connection from the caller (so as that you are able in this particular case to connect only ONCE to the database, but do as many selects as you need).

Third, don't use ExecuteReader, use ExecuteScalar.

Furthemore: You shouldn't do too many things on FormLoad (the UI will freeze).
And why are you querying the database based on the value of a label ?
Was that just a sample you wrote really fast to show us what you mean or is it the actual business logic ?

```
private string GetRoomName_BasedOn_RoomNumber(string roomNumber, MyConnection connection) {
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
         command.CommandText = ("Select Room_name from firstfloor where Room_no=(?room)");
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?room", roomNumber);
         //command.ExecuteNonQuery();

         object response = command.ExecuteScalar();

         return response as string; // consider <null> as a "No such Room Number" signal
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = label1.Text;
    string b = label2.Text;

    string connString = "Server=Localhost;Database=this;Uid=root;password=root";
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
       connection.Open();
       button1.Text = this.GetRoomName_BasedOn_RoomNumber(a, connection);
       button2.Text = this.GetRoomName_BasedOn_RoomNumber(b, connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: Close but there are few errors in your code, Where did you declare command type? And you didn't assign connection to command object.

Comment: no overload for method GetRoomName_BasedOn_RoomNumber' takes 1 argument ..

Comment: ok.. Sorry 'bout that. Got carried away. Please check the edit

Comment: connection must be valid and open ..

Comment: try the new and improved version :) (now.. with opened connection !)

Comment: i think there is an error in this part of the code command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?room", a); it always fetch the "a"

Comment: just replace "a" with "roomNumber" inside the GetRoomName_BasedOn_RoomNumber method

Comment: update: i commented the `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` which had nothing to do with what the `GetRoomName_BasedOn_RoomNumber` method

Answer (score 0):

For example you can refactor your code and extract the following code into a method:

```
  private void DoSomething(MySqlConnection connection)
{            
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = ("Select Room_name from firstfloor where Room_no=(?room)");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?room", b);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                button2.Text = reader["Room_name"].ToString();
            }
        }

    }
```